# Groovy coerce map to GroovyRowResult

Tags: groovy

I am trying to create a `Map` and coerce it to `GroovyRowResult` using the following code:

```
def a = [
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
       my_column: "somevalue"
    ] as groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

if(a.opportunity_id) {
    println("VALUE " + a.my_column)
}

println("GOOD")
```

and see if the `if condition` works correctly. I need to do that because I want to verify in an online playground.

Comment: You haven't asked a question and I'm not sure what the problem is. FWIW, you have not set `a.opportunity_id`.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing a missing property on a `GroovyRowResult` you will get an error like:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: opportunity_id for class: groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: opportunity_id for class: groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult
```

So by just instanciating a new GRR from a map does not make the GRR behave like a map (it's the other way around).

You have to specify all things used later.  E.g.

```
def a = [
    opportunity_id: 666, // XXX
    my_column: "somevalue"
] as groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

if (a.opportunity_id) {
    println("VALUE " + a.my_column)
}
```